# Set Login/Logout Text for Button in Facebook Android SDK 4.0?

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login, facebook-android-sdk, android-facebook

My xml looks like this

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/fb_login_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
android:paddingLeft="15dp"
android:paddingRight="15dp"
android:text="CONNECT WITH FACEBOOK"
android:textColor="@color/white"
android:textSize="20sp"
android:textStyle="bold"
android:background="@drawable/button_fb_login"/>
```

and background drawble xml is

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:state_pressed="true">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#4e69a2" />
        <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#4e69a2" />
        <padding android:bottom="0dip" android:left="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:top="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>

<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#3b5998" />
        <stroke android:width="3dip" android:color="#3b5998" />
        <padding android:bottom="0dip" android:left="0dip" android:right="0dip" android:top="0dip" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Now in android studio preview screen it shows as expected.

[image]

But when I run it on my phone or emulator, it shows "LOG IN WITH FACEBOOK" by default, like this

[image]

How do I get my custom text on running the application?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

use `facebook:login_text` and `facebook:logout_text`

```
 <com.facebook.widget.LoginButton
            android:id="@+id/login_button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            facebook:confirm_logout="false"
            facebook:fetch_user_info="true"
            android:text="testing 123"
            facebook:login_text="LOGIN"
            facebook:logout_text="LOGOUT"
            />
```

If the above doesnt work, try to add following in your values folder

```
<resources>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">LOGIN</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">LOGOUT</string>
</resources>
```

**Update: Possible cause**

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/com/facebook/login/widget/LoginButton.java#L599

**Update 2: Possible Solution**

Override those strings in your `strings.xml`

```
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_out_button">Log out</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button">Log in</string>
<string name="com_facebook_loginview_log_in_button_long">Log in with Facebook</string>
```

Other strings can be found [here](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/res/values/strings.xml)

Comment: Thats the implementation with older version of facebook sdk. I mentioned explicitly that I am using SDK 4.0.

Comment: Thanx for the github link.

Comment: Thanx buddy, It worked when I override those strings.

Comment: This is the correct answer. It worked fine if I've override those strings.

Comment: this isn't working with some languages (like russian). do you know about solution for those languages?

Comment: there must be a `strings.ru.xml` file in your project (If not exists, create one), in which you can override the string.

Comment: its actually `strings-ru.xml`

Comment: Facebook updated their SDK recently and rendered these answers irrelevant. Yay :(  I've fixed my own project now, with the new strings, but the "Other strings can be found here" in answer has dead URL, so fixing that too.

Comment: Thanks to the edit rejectors, the above answer is now wrong again. Yep, thanks guys.

Comment: New strings values https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/res/values/strings.xml

Answer (score 65):

Just need change the attribute accordingly. Refer to : [this](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/blob/master/facebook/src/main/res/values/attrs.xml)

eg:

```
<com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
        xmlns:facebook="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        facebook:com_facebook_login_text="LOGIN"/>
```

Comment: this is perfect solution

Comment: what about in java class?

Comment: Can we add our own custom image in this?